# Mirror network traffic over USB to Ethernet (linux\windows)?

Tags: linux, windows, serial-port, usb, ethernet

I'm trying to mirror network traffic over USB to virtual Ethernet. I have an ARM processor and it send network traffic to my laptop over serial USB port. Now USB is like COM port. I want to capture and mirror it on virtual Ethernet (TAP). What is the straight way to do this?
Any library or package in C++/python that works for both linux & windows will help me.